# Why is there a typescript error when trying to assign FormArrays that appear to be compatible?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics, angular-forms

I would expect from looking at the types that `FormArray<FormControl<string>>` would be assignable to `FormArray<FormControl<string | null>>`, but instead there is an error ([example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ayrpf3?file=src%2Fmain.ts)):

```
Type 'FormArray<FormControl<string>>' is not assignable to type 'FormArray<FormControl<string | null>>'.
  Type 'FormControl<string | null>' is not assignable to type 'FormControl<string>'.
    Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

I'm looking for an explanation for why this is an error. Also, part of the confusion is that the error doesn't make sense, because it seems backward by saying `string | null` is not assignable to `string` on line 2 of the error.

Comment: I think your demo is broken.  Even if you make the two types identical it fails with `The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.`

Comment: I viewed the demo fine.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the issue is that the type being passed into the constructor affects the type of the instance that is created, and it is the fact that the instance types are not compatible that means you can't substitute one for another.

Comment: @FiniteLooper You are correct that there is an error like that when trying to run it, but I don't care about that. The point is to have a simple repro of the compile time error that I mentioned.

Comment: Well i was trying to see what might fix the error, so it's hard to determine when there's always an error.

Comment: @CShark you can cast it: 

y3 = <FormArray<FormControl<string | null>>>y4; 
OR
y3 = <any>y4;

Comment: @Yaroslav I'm not looking for workarounds, I want to know why this is an error

Answer (score 1):

By default, Angular now enforces strict mode. This sets up several things as defined here: https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode

The important part for this purpose is that is enables TypeScript strict mode. Part of that strict mode is "strict null checks" as defined here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

A quote from the above references docs:

> When strictNullChecks is true, null and undefined have their own distinct types and you’ll get a type error if you try to use them where a concrete value is expected.

That basically means that, though it seems you should be able to assign null to a string, TypeScript in strict mode treats null and undefined as their own distinct types.

Hence the error you are seeing.

Comment: I don't believe this is related to the compilation error. `string` should be assignable to `string | null` regardless of whether it's in strict mode or not. It seems to be something specifically related to `FormArray`

Comment: @CShark Your error doesn't say you're trying to assign `string` to `string | null`. It says you're trying to assign a value in a `string | null` type to a `string` type.

Comment: @Logarr read the full error, specifically line 1

Comment: @CShark I did. The error goes away when you remove `nonNullable: true,` from the second array. I'm not super familiar with TypeScript/Angular's type system, but this smells of a boxing issue. You're not actually copying the contents of the non-nullable array into a new object. You're boxing it up in a nullable variable. And that means if you try and add a null value to the array it will try and put it into the array that's in the box, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Logarr This seems possible, but I don't get why this wouldn't apply the same way to Array<>